# How much sleep is too much for my bird?

Tags: behavior, birds, sleep

I have a 22 year old peach fronted conure. I noticed over the last couple weeks that she has been taking more naps during the day. She seems otherwise normal. She has been molting since July/August.

Should I be worried about her naps? What other indicators can I look for to figure out if something is amiss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reached out to my vet about this, and his answer was:

> I am not too concerned about the increase in naps during the day as long as she is otherwise doing well. It seems like she is eating well and acting fine otherwise. Sometimes, conures can sleep more when they are molting. They can also sleep more if they are a little more stressed than usual; if there are any environmental changes or anything like that. Things to look out for would be change in her fecal character or habits. Decreased appetite, or even being "puffed" up.

So looks like all is clear for now. If any other concerned bird owners are wondering the same thing, I would urge also reaching out to their vet if possible to make sure their bird is OK.